# Как вынести " с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Возможно ли как-нибудь вынести, через preg_replace, знак " с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: Вопрос - можно-ли, ответ - да, можно ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем именно с помощью регулярки? Почему бы это не сделать просто функцией str_replace()?

```
$new_str = str_replace('"','',$str);
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Буду юзать str_replace

Answer (score 2):

Ну и по вопросу:

```
$str = preg_replace('/"/', "", $str);
```

Хотя я использовал бы str_replace